# Some emails that have been moved out of inbox into other folders don't sync to Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

I have an odd problem with one of my Exchange users. They sort all of their Outlook emails and everything is fine. However, they recently received an additional computer and on that computer in Outlook, some of those emails are still in their inbox and not sorted into the folders they placed them in.

In webmail these emails are sorted like they're supposed to be...very odd.

Any idea how this could happen and what I can do to get the emails to sync up to the Exchange server?

The user's old computer is running Windows XP and the new one is Windows 7, using Outlook 2007 on both in an Exchange 2010 environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are they using for their mail box on the computer that isn't sorted? They using the exchange mail box or a PST?

Comment: They're using the Exchange server in cached mode...but the emails were just downloaded recently as it is a new laptop. Perhaps I could try deleting the profile and having her download all the emails again.

Comment: I was more referring to the Data File tab.

Comment: Yeah, I know...they are using Exchange though, not PST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .OST and had her redownload her mailbox and the problem was fixed. Not sure what caused it but it is fixed now in any case.

Thanks for your help Nix!